# Update to Google Sheet

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

Hello I'm trying to update a list of items to Google sheet.

Example I have a csv file data.csv like below

```
Item Name,Qty,Price,Store,Location,Stock
Apple,50,50,Store-1,LA,1000
Mango,30,100,Store-2,SL,5000
Bananna,10,10,Store-3,NY,4000
```

And My Python file code is :

```
client = gspread.service_account_from_dict(credentials)
sheetName = "Sheet1"
obj = {}
with open('data.csv') as f:
    r = csv.reader(f)
    next(f)
    for row in r:
        obj[row[0]] = row[1:6]

spreadsheet = client.open("CSV-to-Google-Sheet")
sheet = spreadsheet.worksheet(sheetName)
values = sheet.get_all_values()[1:]
res = [obj.get(row[0]) if obj.get(row[0]) else ["", ""] for row in values]
sheet.update("B2", res, value_input_option="USER_ENTERED")
```

**So Whenever we run script,**

**It should check if Apple exists in Google sheet `Column 1 Item Name` and then it should start filling remaining columns**

[image]

**Qty to Qty column**

**Price to Price column**

**Store to Store column**

**Location to Location column**

**Stock to Stock column**

Answer (score 1):

You can get your current google sheet data into a dataframe using:

```
import pygsheets

gc = pygsheets.authorize(service_file=service_file)
sh = gc.open("Sheet1")
wks = sh.sheet1
old_data = pd.DataFrame(wks.get_all_records())
```

Then you can do any checks you want on the dataframe and update the google sheet back using.

```
df = new_data # your new dataset (dataframe)

found = old_data[old_data['Item Name'].str.contains('Apple')]
if found.count() > 0: 
   wks.set_dataframe(df, (1, 1))
```

Comment: So if I have 1000 row of data in csv this is difficult to mention all the items

Comment: I don't understand the question. But 1000 rows of data wont affect the update of the worksheet. It will append it to the old worksheet. Better still, if you have datetime field, you can take advantage of that to know where to start the update from.

Comment: So the above code updates only Apple row or all the row in csv.

Comment: It will update all rows and columns once Apple is confirmed present

Comment: So next time when I need to update another csv file with different items,  then how to update cozz there will be no apple there will be different items.